# Generate EAN13 barcode

Tags: plugin-development

The project that I'm working on requires that I generate an EAN13 barcode for display on vouchers.

I'm attempting to implement the following as a Craft Plugin: https://github.com/rlt3/php-barcode

The part that I am unclear about is how exactly to define my Model to return an image to the calling template. Do I even need a Model ?

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a late reply (But hope you can use this!), but I created a plugin to output barcodes within Craft templates via Twig:

https://github.com/madebyshape/barcode

I created it because one of our clients required a barcode to be output in to a generated PDF that got sent to their customers.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I highly recommend reading the Craft plugin docs: https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins

You can certainly use a [Model](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/models), but it depends on how you want to architect the rest of your plugin.  I like to think of a Model as a convenient way of transporting objects/data across the different layers of your plugin ([Template Variables](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/variables), [Services](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/services), [Controllers](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers), etc.).

That plugin currently will just generate the image and [output it directly to the browser](https://github.com/rlt3/php-barcode/blob/master/ean.php#L167), which may or may not be what you want from a template.  What you may want to do is take that image and save it to the file system (in a temporary or permanent public place) and have your Twig template reference that file directly.